# React filter only filters based on last value in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using filter method for filtering data but it doesn't work as my `action.payload` is an array and I am using the `forEach` method to loop through array of values. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Below is my code:

```js
const searchParameters = data && Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data));

action.payload.forEach((i) => {
  filterData = state.products.filter((item) =>
    searchParameters.some((parameter) =>
      item[parameter]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(i.toLowerCase())
    )
  );
});
```

My `action.payload` has following values `["Red", "Blue", "Green"]` but it only filters out according to the last element in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My `action.payload` has following values `["Red", "Blue", "Green"]`
> but it only filters out according to the last element in the array.

That is correct since the current implementation loops over the payload and overwrites the `filterData` value, so the last iteration is the value that "sticks".

If you are filtering `state.products` then this is the object that should be iterated on the outer loop, the payload array will be the inner-most loop.

Example:

```js
const searchParameters = data && Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data));

const colors = action.payload.map(val => val.toLowerCase());

const getItemParam = (item, parameter) =>
  (item[parameter] ?? "").toString().toLowerCase();

const filterData = state.products.filter(item => {
  return searchParameter.some(parameter => {
    const itemParam = getItemParam(item, parameter);
    return colors.some(color => itemParam.includes(color));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I am guessing that both payload and state.products are arrays.
You may want to initialize the `filterData` from outside the `forEach` because most likely it is being overwritten on every loop hence filters out according to the last element in the array

```js
const searchParameters = data && Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data));
let filterData = state.products;

action.payload.forEach((i) => {
   filterData = filterData.filter((item) =>
     searchParameters.some((parameter) =>
       item[parameter]
         .toString()
         .toLowerCase()
         .includes(i.toLowerCase())
    )
  );
});
```